# Why is "together" spelled with "thong"

Tags: kanji, etymology

What is the etymology of 一緒{いっしょ}に? Why kanji 緒{しょ} (meaning "thong") is used in this expression, and not 諸{しょ} (meaning "together")?

Comment: It has plenty of meanings; why not interpret it as 'string', 'lace', 'tie', or 'knot'?

Comment: Aren't those synonyms to "thong"? They still do not have any connection to "together".

Comment: Strings, ties, laces, and knots tie things 'together', don't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic meaning of 緒 *sho* is "thread" (or "thread end").  Some say 一緒 *issho* comes from the homophone 一所 *issho*, "in one place", which appears in old works such as the *Heike Monogatari* with the meaning of "together".  If this is correct, then 一緒 *issho* must be a [reanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reanalysis_(linguistics)) meant to distinguish the "together" nuances from the basic "physically at the same place" meaning. That is:

- In the first stage, you have 一所 *issho* = "one place; physically at one (and the same) place".
- Then 一所 *issho* starts to be used metaphorically to mean "together", not just in the same place but also "performing in combination", "united in a single whole", "in a relationship" etc.
- Then 一緒 *issho* is devised to distinguish the latter nuances.

Why did they choose "thread" to mean "together"? I don't know, but if I had to speculate, to me at least the idea of "together as if in a single thread" brings to mind things like this:
[image]

Why not use 諸 *sho-*? Well, the meaning of the word 諸 *sho-* isn't "together" at all.  Rather, it's "all" or "various", used as a prefix quantifier (in constructions like 諸君 *sho-kun* = "all of you in the audience; ladies and gentlemen!" or 諸国 *sho-koku* = "the various countries, the many provinces").  You can say, for example, 「諸国が別々に解決した」 "each/every country settled it separately". Not only the meaning doesn't match, but also the grammar doesn't fit.  諸 *sho-* was already a prefix in its Chinese origins, so it would probably feel weird and nonsensical to put a prefix modifying a *ni* in the already-existing expression *issho-ni* (which, you'll note, makes perfect sense with the original analysis as 一所に). 緒 *sho*, by contrast, is a standalone noun, not a prefix.

Comment: Can KanjiDic be trusted at all? http://www.edrdg.org/kanjidic/kanjd2index.html One of the meaning is "together" in this dictionary.

Comment: Kanji themselves don't have unequivocal meanings; kanji represent morphemes and words, and it's those morphemes and words that have meanings. The prefix *sho-* as written by 諸 means "various" or "several"; it never means "together".  諸 is also used to write the somewhat uncommon morpheme *moro*, which has several meanings including "both" (諸手 *morote*), "many, all" (諸人 *morobito*), and "together" (諸寝 *morone*), so that's where kanjidic may have taken the gloss. But you shouldn't put much faith in the notion of "meaning of a kanji", from any dictionary. Look at the words and it'll make sense.